# Terminate user input (e.g., fgets()) when user presses ESC

Tags: c, windows, user-input, keyboard-events

I'm writing a simple C console application in Windows which gets user input in an infinite loop.

I want the application to be in "reading mode" and keep reading until the user presses a quit key (e.g. escape).

How can I both receive user input and terminate it when a specific special key is pressed?

Example:

```
while (1)
{
    // How do I stop loop and input with a specific key hit, e.g., ESC?
    fgets(buff, 255, stdin);
    printf("%s\n", buff);
}
```

Comment: Use `while(!kbhit())` .

Comment: @Kfir I added some example code to clarify what you might wanted to ask. Feel free to adapt the code and add further details to your question if this does not reflect your original question.

Comment: @moooeeeep Thanks, this is pretty accurate.

Comment: Do I correctly interpret this as, you not only want to stop the loop but also quit the (blocking) call to `fgets()` when the user presses ESC?

Comment: @moooeeeep This is correct.

Comment: @Kfir I further updated the question. I hope I got what you meant.

Answer (score 4):

Your are probably looking for

```
while(!kbhit())
```

or you can use  `getch()` included in the `#include <conio.h>` or `getchar()` included in the `#include <stdio.h>` usually used for <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: `iostream`? This is C. not C++. And why is there a `)` after `>`?

Comment: @CoolGuy: That was a typo. Fixed that. Yes I added the option for C as well. It just came to my mind :)

Comment: `getch()` and `getchar()` are different from `kbhit()`. The former is not what the OP wants as it halts the execution of the program until the user enters a key(and the enter key for `getchar()`). The latter is what the OP wants

Comment: @CoolGuy:- I agree and thats why I added that in my answer. Just added all the options. Waiting for OP to comment something or edit the question.

Comment: I suggest saying `stdio.h` instead of `iostream` as the question is about C

Comment: kbhit (or _kbhit) is nice, but will not work when combined with fgets or other input function...as I stated above, I have an infinite loop which gets user input with fgets. thanks for helping!

Comment: @Kfir I think you should clarify in your question that you want to read both formatted input and raw keyboard events. You should also adapt your code to show how the calls to `fgets()` and `kbhit()` interleave to make that point very clear.